# Getting dynamic argument values in inherited class - django

Tags: python, django, paho

I am using `paho mqtt`

written a class

```
 class initializer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = mqtt.Client(mqtt_server+str(int(time.time())))  
        self.client.username_pw_set(
            username=mqtt_username, password=mqtt_password)
        self.client.on_connect = self.on_connect
        self.client.on_subscribe = self.on_subscribe
        self.client.connect(broker, mqtt_port)
        self.client.loop_start()
    def on_connect(self, client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            #app_logger.info("Device Connection Established")
            print("Device Connection Established")
        else:
            #app_logger.info("Bad Connection")
            print("Bad Connection")
    def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
        # app_logger.info(message.topic)
        print("message.topic", message.payload)
```

then I have inherited this class to another class.

```
   class PublishData(initializer):

        def __init__(self):
            super(PublishData, self).__init__()
            self.client.on_message = self.on_message


        def on_message(self, client, userdata, message):
            print("message.payloa", message.payload)

        def begin(self, topic, data):
            self.client.on_message = self.on_message
            self.client.subscribe(
                "topic")
            self.client.publish(
                topic, str(data))
    publishData = PublishData()
    publishData.begin(topic, data)
```

I am getting message in `on_message` function in `initializer` class but I am not getting that message in inherited class. How do I get the `message.payload` value in `PublishData` class?

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Class():

  def method(self, ...):
    ...

def function(..., ...)
```

`method` is a method of an object, `function` is a stand-alone function. It is [different](https://data-flair.training/blogs/python-method-and-function/#:%7E:text=Python%20method%20is%20called%20on%20an%20object%2C%20unlike%20a%20function.&text=Since%20we%20call%20a%20method,something%20or%20returns%20a%20value.) things.

`on_message` method of `mqtt` client expecting callback `function`, but not `method`.

Correct code will be like:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

class init:

  def __init__(self):
  
    def _on_connect(client, userdata, flag, rc):
      print("on connect")

    self.client = mqtt.Client()

    self.client.on_connect = _on_connect


class Publish(init):

  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    def _on_message(client, userdata, message):
      print("on message")

    self.client.on_message = _on_message

mqtt_obj = Publish()
mqtt_obj.client.on_connect(1,2,3,4)
mqtt_obj.client.on_message(1,2,3)
```

output:

```
on connect
on message
```

Comment: but i can't call on_message like that .because on_message function is like this                
 def on_message(self, client, userdata, message) . so if i call on_message i need to pass the args also. but the data is on message.payload

Comment: Ok, change `def _on_message()` to `def _on_message(client, userdata, message)` and `def _on_connect()` to `def _on_connect(client, userdata, flag, rc)`

Comment: got the solution . i have written the initialization in settings.py .client as a variable. then i have imported it. now it is working properly. thanks for your support